# Transfer learning in TF Object Detection API: How to train only the last few layers with weights?

Tags: tensorflow, object-detection, object-detection-api, transfer-learning

I borrowed everything from TF/Model_Zoo (the config files and the model files as is), and started the training by using my images and annotations without changing the config file other than the paths. 
In the original config files, there is no detail the like:

}
freeze_variables: ".*FeatureExtractor."
}

I believe that means everything is getting retrained, is this true? When I look into the tensor-board, it looks like the weights are not changing but the biases are changing. How can I make sure that the weights are also trained?

Also, I would like to retrain only the last 2 (or last n layers) layer, just like regular transfer learning. Is this possible with TF Object Detection API?

Comment: Selin, were you able to train your model's last layers? I am also trying to find an example that trains last layers. Please, let me know if you solved it.

Comment: Said, no. It looks like it is not possible in TF Object Detection API. But, please let me know if you find a way. Also, I am not working on this problem anymore as I have shifted to a different project focusing on a different problem statement for the last 8 months. Thank you!